# What does the Listen parameter control in IO::Socket::SSL

Tags: perl, ssl, websocket

I'm using [`IO::Socket::SSL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL) to create a websocket in Perl:

```
my $ssl_server = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
  Listen        => 10,  # What does this parameter do?
  LocalPort     => 5000,
  Proto         => 'tcp',
  SSL_cert_file => '/etc/webserver/ssl/server.crt',
  SSL_key_file  => '/etc/webserver/ssl/server.key',
) or die "failed to listen: $!";

my $server = Net::WebSocket::Server->new(
    listen => $ssl_server,
    ...
```

I have not been able to figure out what the Listen parameter means or does from this:
http://search.cpan.org/~sullr/IO-Socket-SSL-1.997/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pod

A simple summary of the purpose of this parameter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Listen parameter is not really used in [IO::Socket::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL). Similar to PeerAddr, PeerPort, Blocking, Timeout, Reuse, Proto, LocalPort etc it will just forward all options not starting with `SSL_` to the underlying socket class (i.e. [IO::Socket::IP](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::IP), [IO::Socket::INET6](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::INET6) or [IO::Socket::INET](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::INET), depending on what you have installed).

But, it will look at this parameter to get a useful default setting for the `SSL_server` option, so you don't have to set both `Listen` (for TCP) and `SSL_server` (for SSL).

Comment: Thanks Steffen. Looking at https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::IP does give me a definition of the Listen parameter, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It tells IO::Socket::SSL that the socket is a server socket.  I believe it may also set the allowed length of the queue of pending connections.

Comment: I understood the first part, since that's explicitly mentioned in the cpan link, but the second part isn't. I was a bit confused because I thought it might mean number of connections, but I was able to maintain more than that number of connections. So to summarize, if it's the queue of pending connections that means that (with my code above), there can't be more than 10 connections in the handshake state, but this has no bearing on total connections possible after the handshake state. Also, thanks for your help!